Walrus operator assign variable if method does return None
I read the documentation and lots of examples but do not fully understand how to use it.
I have a function, screen() that returns a screenshot but may return None. I call this in a loop to a variable. The first time its called it never returns None. If it returns None I just want to assign the variable to the previous value. So I can clearly solve this problem like this,
img = screen()
while True:
   temp = screen()
   if temp is not None:
        img = temp


But I want to do this in one line as I call screen() almost 10 times in this loop so it will add up. Note I can not just do,
img = screen() if screen() is not None else img

as this calls the method twice.
I also can not do,
img = screen() or img

as screen() returns a object that has an ambiguous truth value to it, I get a python error.
This is not a similar question to Perform a function on result of another function if not none as they do not fully answer this question.
I tried
img = (s := self.screen(bounding_box)) if s is not None else img

and
(img := self.screen(bounding_box)) if img is not None else img

But they both dont work.

Is screen() under your control (not a 3rd-party library)?  The simplest solution might be to give it a parameter that specifies what to return in cases where it currently returns None.  Then, you can just to img = screen(img).

There's nothing wrong with your existing while loop except perhaps the first call in img = screen() is redundant. Not worth rewriting it into a one-liner.

its third party, returns a screenshot of the screen. But thats actually a good idea, i made a wrapper with a default parameter and basically fixes it. Thank you. Question closed.

just wrap the logic in a function. Don't use these terrible one-liners

This is all about evaluation order.
For an expression like this:
x = v1 if condition else v2

Python needs to evaluate condition before evaluating v1 or v2 and it should not evaluate both.
So, if you want to use the same value in v1 and condition, you need to use the walrus operator in condition, since that gets evaluated first:
img = s if (s := self.screen(bounding_box)) is not None else img

Where, compared to the simplified expression above:

condition is (s := self.screen(bounding_box)) is not None - which can evaluate to True or False depending on the return value of the method call.
v1 is s (the same return value) and v2 is img

Note that the parentheses are needed, since is has higher precedence than :=.
Also note that you're not actually saving anything by writing the one-liner, but the question regarding syntax is answered by the above.
Late edit: if you have reason to use a one-liner like this, consider reversing the order, so that the reader doesn't have to wonder where s is coming from before reading its definition, and there's not the double negative of is not None:
img = img if (s := self.screen(bounding_box)) is None else s


How about something like this:
img = screen()
while True:
    if (temp := screen()) is not None:
        img = temp

